# React Query: InvalidateQuery not working to update users list

Tags: reactjs, react-query, mutation, cache-invalidation

I have a simple app that has a form and list. Currently, I am using query client.InvalidateQueries to update the users' list after submitting the form. As the documentation says, using InvalidateQuery will trigger refetching, but somehow I had not seen an update to the list after adding users. Am I missing something?

Add User

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import Input from '../../elements/Input/Input';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { QueryClient, useMutation } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const CreateItemView = () => {
  function gen4() {
    return Math.random().toString(16).slice(-4);
  }

  function generateID(prefix) {
    return (prefix || '').concat([gen4(), gen4(), gen4(), gen4(), gen4(), gen4(), gen4(), gen4()].join(''));
  }

  const mutation = useMutation(
    (formData) => {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8000/users', formData).then((response) => console.log(response));
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('users');
      },
    },
  );

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const initialValues = {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    channel: '',
  };
  const onSubmit = (values, { resetForm }) => {
    setData([...data, values]);
    const ID = generateID().toString();
    values.id = ID;
    mutation.mutate(values);
    resetForm();
  };
  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().required('Required!'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid format').required('Required!'),
    channel: Yup.string().required('Required!'),
  });
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    onSubmit,
    validationSchema,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <Input type={'text'} name={'name'} id={'name'} label={'Name'} formik={formik} />
        <Input type={'email'} name={'email'} id={'email'} label={'Email'} formik={formik} />
        <Input type={'text'} name={'channel'} id={'channel'} label={'channel'} formik={formik} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateItemView;
```

User's list

```
import React from 'react';
import ListView from './ListView';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

const getUsers = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/users');
  return response.data;
};
const ListContainer = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching } = useQuery('users', getUsers);
  console.log('list', data);
  return <div>{isFetching ? 'loading...' : <ListView dataSource={data} />}</div>;
};

export default ListContainer;
```

Comment: you are not showing the query that listens to the 'users' query. is it using the same query client? what are the react-query-devtools  saying?

Answer (score 3):

You have to **return** the fetch function in the mutation. The `onSuccess` handler will fire when the promise is resolved.

```js
const mutation = useMutation(
    formData => {
      return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/users', formData)
               .then((response) => console.log(response));
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('users');
      },
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

i  think  the solution for your problem is to  replace this :

```
 onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('users');
      },
```

By this :

```
onSettled:() => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries('users');
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the same instance of queryClient from the root of your app which is accessible via the `useQueryClient()` hook.
Hence you should be doing `const queryClient = useQueryClient()` instead of generating new instance with `const queryClient = new QueryClient()`.